# How does Reddit fetch the posts with maximum rating or hotness from its huge database?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, web-deployment, reddit

I know the algorithm behind Reddit ([it's here](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588)). But how is it possible to sort the posts according the algorithm and retrieve the posts with maximum rating as there are more than a billions posts in Reddit?

I researched a bit and found that Reddit has an extra field which stores the rating of the post. But as the rating function takes current time as a parameter I am not able to figure out how they update the rating of all the posts as time passes. There is a also a possibility of setting a date in the past as reference for all the posts.

But it can create an overflow as the size of the rating field is infinite and rating of new posts increases further and further. How does this work?

Comment: (note: *i know nothing*): I would bet that they update them asynchronously and keep a cached result in the database.  So at any point in time it is a bit old, but they iterate through the database fast enough to make it look fine.  And any "instantaneous" things you see are simply client-side and will *eventually* be processed to update the sort

Comment: the formula is based on when the post was created, right? I don't see where it uses the current time